# How would I go about switching between two projects in Gitlab using IntelliJ?

Tags: git, intellij-idea, gitlab

I'm currently learning how to use Git using Gitlab. I have created a new project in Gitlab aside from my previous (first) project. I haven't been able to figure out a way, using git commands, to switch between the two projects. I have Windows Powershell set up in IntelliJ as my terminal. I am aware of a couple commands that may be related, such as setupstream, but I'm not sure what to do from here. How would I go about switching between two projects in Gitlab using the command line in IntelliJ?

Comment: Welcome to SO! When you place a question try to add a minimum content: input sample, expected output sample, what did you try, research and where are you stuck. What did you try?

Comment: `cd ../otherproject`?

Comment: Thanks for the input. Thus far I have set up my first git project to be able to push to and pull from. I have created another project within gitlab and I have cloned it in IntelliJ. I have tried changing directories with cd.. and going to my other project, but I am not familiar with how to ensure I'm pushing and pulling from the current directory I am in. For example, if I am in ../project1 and I switch to ../project2 to work on, when I add, commit, and push, how do I ensure it is going to add/commit/push to project2 and not project 1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the [Module](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-and-managing-modules.html) of your [IntelliJ project](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-and-managing-projects.html), you can add many "[content root](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/content-roots.html)"

In your case, 2 content roots, one for each local clone folder.

IntelliJ will detect their respective `.git/` subfolder, alongside with their remote URL.

> if I am in `../project1` and I switch to ../project2 to work on, when I add, commit, and push, how do I ensure it is going to add/commit/push to project2 and not project 1

On IntelliJ, you would have to switch: simply modify a file from one or the other content root, and IntelliJ will add/commit/push according to their respecting .git/ local repository.